# Query to filter out Bad address data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a SQL query on Snowflake that would generate all incorrect addresses from a database.

```
select *
from
TABLE1
where    contains (address_line_1,'@')
```

Or should I use NOT REGEXP_LIKE ?

Basically, I need to get all the addresses with @, ! or similar symbols.

```
select *
from
TABLE1
where    contains (address_line_1,'@')
```

Or should I use NOT REGEXP_LIKE ?

Answer (score 1):

The regex approach is probably quicker to write and add characters to e.g.

```
REGEXP_LIKE(address_line_1,'.*[!@].*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can find address containing any of `[@!]` characters in single check:

```
where address_line_1 REGEXP '[@!]'
```

or to filter them out:

```
where NOT (address_line_1 REGEXP '[@!]')
```

You can add more characters into the character class `[@!]`. [Special characters in regex](https://.,%20+,%20*,%20?,%20%5E,%20$,%20(,%20),%20%5B,%20%5D,%20%7B,%20%7D,%20%7C,%20%5C.) should be backslashed, for example `\+` for plus sign: '[@!+]' -checks for any of @, !, +.